# React & AmCharts 4 Sankey Diagram Issue

Tags: reactjs, amcharts4

I do have a data around 10,000.

Now while plotting the Sankey Diagram using amchart4 in Reactjs I am getting this error 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'

Comment: Instead of using amchart4 you can use  amchart5 because  getting less feature in v4, so, maybe due to that you are getting error

Comment: This error is not related to the tech you are using. Maximum call stack size exceeded means you have recursion in the code that never stops. Something like function a() { a() }